# Adding columns for categoies

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, categorization

I have a table with a name and date of birth. I converted the dob into birth-month using a datepart. Now I need to add a column to describe whether the birth month is in the first half of the year or second half. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Here's my code so far:

```
SELECT patient_nm, dob
FROM edw_emr_ods.patients;

SELECT patient_nm, datepart(month from edw_emr_ods.patients.dob) as dob_month
FROM edw_ods.patients;
```

I know this is probably a pretty basic question but any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT 
    patient_nm
    ,DATEPART(MONTH, edw_emr_ods.patients.dob) AS dob_month 
    ,CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, edw_emr_ods.patients.dob) <= 6 THEN 'First Half'
        WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, edw_emr_ods.patients.dob) > 6 THEN 'Second Half'
        ELSE 'not a valid date'
    END
FROM edw_ods.patients;
```

FYI - your code had a typo and wouldn't execute. Your DATEPART function needs to have the datepart (month) followed by a comma and the expression containing the date. I fixed it in my example above.